# Size of centered div is small

Tags: html, css

Hello I centered div using grid and now it is very small. When I used absolute centering the size was correct but I do not want to have absolute positioned element becasue it breaks flow. How can I solve the problem?

```css
.center-cart-table {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.cart-specification-row {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(51, 204, 51, 0.774), rgba(74, 187, 74, 0.753), rgba(75, 196, 75, 0.726));
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.cart-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item-row {
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-cart-table">
  <div>
    <div class="cart-specification-row">
      <div>Name</div>
      <div>Quantity</div>
      <div>Price</div>
    </div>
    {% for item in order_items %}
    <div class="item-row">
      <p>{{ item.item.title }}</p>
      <p>{{item.quantity}}</p>
      <p>{{item.item.price}}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %} Total: {{ cart.total }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `grid-template-columns` to set the track sizing of the grid columns (column width) to `1fr`. This will make a one-column grid that spans the entire width.

Here's more info on [grid-template-columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) and the [Grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout) in general.

```css
.center-cart-table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr; /* Sets column track size */
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.cart-specification-row {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(51, 204, 51, 0.774), rgba(74, 187, 74, 0.753), rgba(75, 196, 75, 0.726));
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.cart-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item-row {
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-cart-table">
    <div class="cart-specification-row">
      <div>Name</div>
      <div>Quantity</div>
      <div>Price</div>
    </div>
    {% for item in order_items %}
    <div class="item-row">
      <p>{{ item.item.title }}</p>
      <p>{{item.quantity}}</p>
      <p>{{item.item.price}}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %} Total: {{ cart.total }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
.cart-specification-row > div{
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
```